# Python: Is there any reason a subset of a list would sort differently than the original list?

Tags: python, sorting

**edit:** FYI for all you paranoid people, the repro code no longer uses eval.

---

I'm not going to say I discovered a bug in Python (which would get me instantly downvoted), but this is some preeetty weird behavior. I have a list `pairs` and call `sort` on it with a custom `key` function that does not change state. Then I take a subset of `pairs` (in the same order), and call `sort` again with the same key function. The result is different from the original subset. Is this possible?

I have provided a repro for you all [as a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesqo/61aabf53ffb929f37c8678288f4dda47). Steps to prepare:

1. Download all 4 files (`dpd.txt`, `index_map.txt`, `ids.txt` and `weirdsortbehavior.py`) and place them in the same directory
2. Run the Python program (note: with Python 3, have not tested for Python 2). For me it printed out

   ```
   0 1916
   1 0
   ```
3. Marvel at this behavior.

What is the explanation for this and what can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you at least provide a minimal example *here* instead of having us download stuff from GitHub?.

Comment: I'm not going to execute your code because it has an `eval` of a huge text blob too big to read.

Comment: @Li357 Sorry, I was unable to find a minimal example. When I tried to reproduce this for small instances it stopped occurring.

Comment: You first sort by -dpd[index_map[id_]] then by id_.lower(), the result looks fine to me.

Comment: @TwistedSim The weird behavior is that `Castle.Core` is initially being ranked higher than jQuery, then it's being ranked lower, even though the latter has more downloads per day so jQuery should always be ranked higher.

Comment: @Li357 I did reproduce it (look at the gist), but I couldn't make the repro smaller because the behavior disappeared.

Comment: @wim @Li357 FYI I have updated the code not to use `eval`.

Comment: Since I don't have pandas installed I changed `dpd` to `dpd = [float(k.split(',')[1] or 0) for k in open('dpd.txt', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()[1:]]` and I got the output `7 1` followed by `1 0`.

Comment: Your sort doesn't appear to be sorting. Have you examined what your key function actually returns?

Comment: Alternatively, calling sort with the pandas data structure didn't actually do what you think it did, as in my code I commented out the first sort, the first line of output was `0 1916`, which tells me your code with pandas didn't cause the sorting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found why. That is because there are some `nan` in `dpd.txt`.

And `nan` is unable to compare:

`float('nan') > 1 # False` while `float('nan') < 1 # False`

So this totally breaks comparison.

If you change your key compare function to:

```
def _key(id_):
    import math
    result = -dpd[index_map[id_]], id_.lower()
    if math.isnan(result[0]):
        result = 0, id_.lower()
    return result
```

It will work.

Comment: Yep, this was why. Thank you!